# One to many relationship MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to mysql and am trying to link two tables and am not sure how, i have a products table with a list of products in a restaurant, the column in this table are

- ID(primary key)
- name
- price

The other table is called extras, this table contains extra things that you can add to your order but are optional,  for when buying chicken you have an option of spicy and non spicy, 
Some products have more than one extras, for instance a product can have the option of choosing three extras.

The extras table at the moment only has

- ID(primary key)
- name

not sure how to link the two or where to put foreign constraints.

UPDATE

Same extra may also belong to numerous products

Comment: you just need to add product_id to your extra table

Comment: normally one would expect some foreign key field in the "extras" table that points to the "products" table.  F.e. something like : `extras.product_id` --> `products.id`

Comment: It doesn't look like these two tables can be linked, since the number of extras seems to vary based on the product you'd want to have a table of product_extras.  That table would only need to have two columns, one for a product ID and one for an extras ID.

Comment: On top of what @JoshGivens mentioned above, you may need a field in the product table to indicate the limit of extras (ex: "pick up to 3 of the extras"). ...and you may need to differentiate between "extras" and "options" (ex: pizzas usually come with a "pick x toppings" deal, but do not count the sauce choice as a "topping")

Comment: If a certain extra (like "spicy") may be applicable to more than one product ("chicken", "beef", "pork",  ...) then you have a many-many relationship, and would need a separate table that connects both: `extra_product`, with two foreign keys `product_id` and `extra_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A joining/linking table usually uses many-to-many relationships by joining the 2 parent tables/primary keys to allow many products to have many extras or no extras at all.

[image]

so for example:

eg:
Product IDs (primary keys) are: 1, 2, 3
Product names are: chicken wings, chicken breast, chicken fillet

Extras IDs (primary keys) are: 1, 2, 3
Extras names are: mild, medium, hot

Wings, breasts and fillet have the option of all three of the extras, so the product_extras table would end up looking something like this:

```
product_extras_id | product_id | extras_id
------------------------------------------
1                 | 1          | 1
2                 | 1          | 2
3                 | 1          | 3
4                 | 2          | 1
5                 | 2          | 2
6                 | 2          | 3
7                 | 3          | 1
8                 | 3          | 2
9                 | 3          | 3
```

Answer (score 1):

With products having many extras and extras applying to many products this is actually a many to many relationship.

```
create table products(ID int auto_increment Primary Key,
Name varchar(50),
Price decimal(6,2));

create table extras(ID int auto_increment Primary Key,
Name varchar(50));

create table product_extras(Product int Not Null,
Extra int Not Null,
FOREIGN KEY(Product) References products(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(Extra) References extras(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Something akin to this should work for you, though you may want to change the datatypes based off preference and what data actually needs to go in there.

Answer (score 1):

In your case one product may have many extras(1 to many) and many products may be having same extra thing(many to 1). Thus, this is a many to many relationship and for such relations we need 3 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE products ( 
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name VARCHAR(50), 
    price DECIMAL(10.2)
 );

 CREATE TABLE extras (
      id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name VARCHAR(50)
 );

 CREATE TABLE products_extras (
      id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      pro_id INT,
      FOREIGN  KEY(pro_id) REFERENCES products(id),
      ext_id INT,
      FOREIGN KEY(ext_id) REFERENCES extras(id)
 );
```